# BIRT: How to autofit width of last column when adjusting cell width

Tags: width, cell, birt, adjustment

I am currently working on a report that needs the rightmost column to be aligned.

I found a report that I want to copy the behavior wherein when I adjust the width of the cell of the whole group, the last column of cells inside it adjust as well.

I tried comparing the properties of these 2 reports to know the correct value to adjust but with no luck.

Below is how they look like:

What should I do so that the last column in table inside the cell autofits when I adjust the cell width?

Report 1 (Correct Behavior):

[image: Adjusting the cell width also adjusts width of the **Amount** column]

Reprt 2 (Incorrect Behavior):

[image: Adjusting the cell width does not adjust width of the **Amount** column]

Comment: This probably depends on the report property "Auto Layout" or "Fixed Layout".

Comment: Both Report 1 and Report 2 on the example is on Fixed Layout

Answer (score 5):

Basically, dealing with column widths in BIRT is easy:

1)
The grid/table has a width property. As soon as you change *any* column width using the mouse in the designer, BIRT will set this property.
The grid/table width property can be empty (it can be cleared in the property editor). In this case, BIRT uses all the available width.

2)
Every column has a width property. As soon as you change *any* column width using the mouse in the designer, BIRT will set this property for *all* columns. The column width property can be empty for some of the columns (it can be cleared in the column's property editor). In this case, BIRT computes the width of the grid/table (see 1) and subtracts the widths of those columns which specify a width. The remaining width is shared equally for those columns without a width specified.

3) Avoid mixing the unit '%' with absolute units like 'pt' for different column widths of the same grid/table.

4) Avoid using the unit 'px' unless you know what you're doing (what size is a pixel?).

5) Avoid specifying column widths whose sum is >= the table/grid's width.

Keep in mind the sentence "In this case, BIRT uses the available with" in rule 1. The available width comes from the container (the parent-element in the layout structure tree).
And so on, recursively, until you come to the width of the body element.
For the PDF and the Word Emitter, this width depends on the master page width and margins.

For HTML output, I don't know what the body element's width is. Probably, it's undefined.
Personally, I never use the HTML emitter, so I cannot help you here.

And the report property "Auto layout" or "Fixed layout" certainly plays a role. For PDF and Word output, one should use "Fixed Layout".

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouse.

This time that did the trick. Really.

I gave the exact width by numbers, the result was terrible.

I've just read your answer than I grabbed the column with the mouse - the final width was the same, but it worked! Maybe there is some bug in the input mechanism...